# Passing Vlans between HP Procurve and Dell Powerconnect switches

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve, dell

I have a core switch which is a HP Procurve switch with Vlans 1, 10, 20.  I'm trying to setup an edge Dell switch.  On the HP I have untagged vlan 1 and tagged vlans 10, 20 on port 1.  On the Dell switch I changed port 16 to 'switchport general', with 10, 20 tagged (I think I had vlan 1 as the PVID).  I then set port 2 as Switchport Access vlan 10.

When I connect a computer to port 2 on the Dell switch, it gets an IP from the vlan 1.

I haven't edited any encapsulation settings, so I assume they're both 802.1q, and I can't see any reference to encapsulation in the running config.

I have successful linked to HP Procurves before, I just haven't used a Dell switch before.

Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

I'm also a little confused about, when to use 'general' and when to use 'trunk' on the Dell switch.

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mode general and trunk are both used for VLAN trunking

mode general
You may choose multiple tagged and untagged vlans, default is tagged

mode trunk 
You may define one native vlan, all others are tagged

mode access
You may define a single untagged VLAN

Could you post your configuration for further troubleshooting? If you set the interface to mode access and specified the VLAN there should be no issue.